# Error when citing in the frontmatter (Spanish)

Tags: biblatex, citing, babel, apa-style, front-matter

I'm trying to reference an article in an abstract chapter but I'm getting lots of errors that I don't understand.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{book}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
Trying to cite \cite{Wren1996}.

\end{document}
```

Implementing any (no need to apply them all) of the following changes make it works again:

- Changing `\frontmatter` for `\mainmatter` or deleting it
- Deleting the `style=apa` option of the `biblatex` package
- Deleting the `\usepackage{babel}`

The content of the refs.bib file is:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@InCollection{Wren1996,
  author    = {Anthony Wren},
  title     = {Scheduling, timetabling and rostering {\textemdash} A special relationship?},
  booktitle = {Practice and Theory of Automated Timetabling},
  year      = {1996},
  publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  pages     = {46--75},
  doi       = {10.1007/3-540-61794-9_51},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:biblatex;}
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by a combination of the way `biblatex` handles back-references (records of where a source was cited), and a redefinition by Spanish babel of the `\@roman` macro, which makes it unexpandable. The result is that it is being included in an `.aux` file and then (I believe) expanded prematurely as part of the creation of an internal list.

You have a number of options:

1. As noted by gusbrs in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471403/5404), load Spanish babel with options that prevent it from the critical redefinition. This will, however, mean that you do not get small capital roman page-numbering.
2. Load `biblatex-apa` with `backref=false`. As it happens, the APA style does not require back references. `biblatex-apa` only prints them if you set `apabackref=true`. It's not clear to me why it **always** sets the package `backref` option true, but it doesn't need to. Anyway, if you don't want back references, and you apparently don't need them to comply with APA style, that's an easy option.
3. Disable backreferences **in the front matter**. To do this put `\backtrackerfalse` at the start of the frontmatter and `\backtrackertrue` at the end. Once you are in `\mainmatter` there is no problem anyway.
4. Get hacky. The following document illustrates one possible hack: we save the "working" version of `\@roman` before loading `babel`, and then redefine the critical macro in `\biblatex` so that it distinguishes between `\frontmatter` and `\backmatter`. Actually, it has a known bug. The standard classes (as far as I can tell) don't separately track whether they are in `\frontmatter` or `\backmatter`, but set a single boolean switch dependent on `\mainmatter`. That will mean, given my definition, that citations in `\backmatter` will (wrongly) get back references with roman page numbers. To avoid that, you would have to add some additional flag to track backmatter. Also, the roman pagenumbers are **not** in small capitals; to get **that** to work would be still more work.

   ```
   \documentclass[spanish]{book}
   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @InCollection{Wren1996,
     author    = {Anthony Wren},
     title     = {Scheduling, timetabling and rostering {\textemdash} A special relationship?},
     booktitle = {Practice and Theory of Automated Timetabling},
     year      = {1996},
     publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
     pages     = {46--75},
     doi       = {10.1007/3-540-61794-9_51},
   }
   \end{filecontents}
   \makeatletter
   % Clone an expandable form of @roman before babel is loaded
   \let\@oldroman\@roman
   % Define an expandable equivalent of \thepage which distinguishes
   % between front and mainmatter
   \def\my@safepage{% 
      \if@mainmatter
       \thepage
      \else
       \@oldroman\c@page
      \fi}
   \makeatother
   \usepackage{babel}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,apabackref=true]{biblatex}
    \makeatletter
     \def\blx@addbackref@i#1{%
      \ifbacktracker
        \blx@leavevmode
        \if@filesw
         \protected@write\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@backref
            {\the\c@instcount}{#1}{\the\c@refsection}%
            {\my@safepage}{\noexpand\the\c@page}}%<-substitute \my@safepage for \thepage
        \fi
        \fi}
   \makeatother
   \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
   \begin{document}
   \frontmatter

   \chapter{Introduction}
   Trying to cite \cite{Wren1996}.

   \mainmatter

   Trying to cite again: \cite{Wren1996}

   \clearpage

   And again \cite{Wren1996}

   \backmatter

   \printbibliography

   \end{document}
   ```

Unless you actually need backreferences to the frontmatter (which seems super hard to believe) I think the second or third options are much the best. My redefinition is really not what it should be to be robust. Meanwhile, either the Spanish babel maintainers need to think about their methods and/or the biblatex maintainers may want to think about how and when commands from the backreferencing commands in the aux file get expanded.

Comment: Mhhh, if this can be fixed at all, I actually think `biblatex` should fix this. I'm not sure if we can blame `babel-spanish` for that. As mentioned under gusbrs' answer, things only go wrong when `biblatex` tries to add `\es@scroman {i}` to an internal list for backreferences. Surely that should work. That list is later used to populate the `pageref` list, where `\es@scroman {i}` could again be problematic, because the list is not just printed as is, it is compressed.

Comment: @moewe Yes, maybe I was unfair to them. Biblatex is making assumptions about how `\thepage` will expand in `\@protected@write` (essentially that it will fully expand). OTOH, I'm not sure that redefining a macro as basic as `\@roman` so as to make it unexpandable is actually sensible either, because `biblatex` may not be the only package to make these assumptions, though I can see why the Spanish babel package takes that approach.

Comment: @moewe I've notified it as an issue on github.

Comment: This isn't still THE solution to the problem but it works for me because I don't need backreferences at all. As an aside, in Spanish, the correct way to write roman numbers is in capital letters (it is written in the comment by @gusbrs in Spanish, so non-Spanish speakers may have missed it). I can't say if the issue is in the es-babel or the biblatex package, not enough TeX knowledge.

Comment: @jlaraval, If uppercase is what you desire, you could go with `es-ucroman` instead of `es-lcroman`. If I recall correctly of my testing, things work with the former.

Comment: I opened an issue for `biblatex-apa` to discuss the use of the `backref` option there. On first glance there seems to be no reason why `apa.bbx` should set `backref=true`. https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/72

Answer (score 7):

This is not a complete answer, for I cannot figure out how things are interacting here, or the reason why they break. But I was able to pin down the source of the problem, and it has to do with `babel`'s change of roman numerals, which are used in lower case for page numbering of the front matter in the standard classes, `book` included. `babel` `spanish` changes that:

> Como en castellano no se usan números romanos en minúscula, `\roman` se redefine para que los dé en versalitas. La opción de paquete `es-minimal` los desactiva con `es-ucroman`, y `es-sloppy` con `es-lcroman`.

So, you can opt out of this particular option, if you are OK with lower case roman numbering in your front matter. This can be done with the option `es-lcroman` passed to `babel`.

```
\documentclass[spanish]{book}

\usepackage[es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
Trying to cite \cite{Wren1996}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, if someone else can explain what is really going on, and why this affects `biblatex-apa` but not other standard styles, please. I'm also curious.

Comment: The error is coming in via `\@abx@aux@backref`. It *will* reproduce even in standard styles if backrefs are on, and conversely will disappear from `apa` if they are off (option `backref=false`). I think it has to do in some way that I cannot understand with the introduction of a macro `\es@scroman` into the fourth argument of `\@abx@aux@backref`.

Comment: @PaulStanley Ah, I didn't get the interaction with `backref`, nice catch! Tricky problem this one, eh?

Comment: Yes. I'm inclined to blame the maintainers of Spanish babel, who apparently have redefined `\thepage` so that it fiddles with expansion and dumps a macro into the `.aux` file. I suppose one could patch `\blx@addbackref@i` to re-redefine `\thepage` in frontmatter ...

Comment: @PaulStanley Just reiterating, if you do reach a conclusion, do not hesitate to add another answer.

Comment: The issue is definitely `\es@scroman`. But I'm not sure what the 'correct' solution would be. Things only really start to break as soon as `biblatex` tries to add `\es@scroman  {i}` to an internal list. Naively I would have expected that this should work. Still none the wiser about a solution, though

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts so far. For the moment i'll go with the `es-lcroman` option of the babel package.

Comment: Also, I've reported the issue to es-babel team as suggested by @PaulStanley, I'll let you know if there is any solution from their part

Comment: Not the complete answer, but essentially the right answer because you've done the right thing: "read the docs" :-). Not a bug and documented in the manual.

Comment: @JavierBezos I appreciate your comment and understand that, from the point of view of `babel-spanish`, this is a feature. But I don't think it should break a document. So, I do believe there is something to be fixed there, though I don't know if from `biblatex`'s or `babel-spanish`'s side (or both).

Answer (score 2):

> tl;dr This was a bug that is fixed in `biblatex` v3.13 (2019/08/17).
>   An update should fix the issue.

`biblatex` made some (unrealistic, as it turns out) implicit assumptions about the value of `\thepage` for its `backref` functionality.

While it is not outright assumed that only Arabic or Roman numerals are used, the implementation with macros like `\ifinlistcs` work better when `\thepage` expands to something that contains only alphanumeric characters.

In particular `biblatex` would throw an error when it tried to check if `\es@scroman {i}` (the value of `\thepage` on the first page of the front matter) is already contained in the list of pages where a particular entry was cited. Furthermore, `biblatex` would have issues adding non-expandable content like `\es@scroman {i}` to the `pageref` list, because it would try to expand the list items completely when they were added to the list.

Following [Paul Stanley](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5404/paul-stanley)'s bug report at the `biblatex` bug tracker https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/859, the bug was fixed with commit https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/071809e815f692074f6af0b059fde7dae9e01ef1. The fix is included from `biblatex` v3.13 onwards.

This fix is equivalent to the modified code in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[spanish]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backref,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
% \ifinlist{<item>}{<list>} is not a good idea
% for printable stuff according to the etoolbox docs
% for \ifinlist (p. 31)
\newrobustcmd{\blx@ifprintableinlist}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\blx@tempa{\endgroup
      \@secondoftwo}%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
      \ifstrequal{##1}{#1}
        {\def\blx@tempa{\endgroup
           \@firstoftwo}%
         \listbreak}
        {}}%
    \dolistloop{#2}%
  \expandafter\blx@tempa}

\newrobustcmd{\blx@ifprintableinlistcs}[2]{%
  \expandafter\blx@ifprintableinlistcs@i\csname #2\endcsname{#1}}
\long\def\blx@ifprintableinlistcs@i#1#2{\blx@ifprintableinlist{#2}{#1}}

% use the more robust \blx@ifprintableinlist instead of \ifinlist
\protected\def\blx@aux@backref#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@pref@#3@\detokenize{#2}}
    {\global\cslet{blx@pref@#3@\detokenize{#2}}\@empty
     \expandafter\blx@onlypreamble\csname blx@pref@#3@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname}
    {}%
  \blx@ifprintableinlistcs{#4}{blx@pref@#3@\detokenize{#2}}
    {}
    {\listcsgadd{blx@pref@#3@\detokenize{#2}}{#4}}%
  \blx@addpagesum{#1}{#5}}

\let\abx@aux@backref\blx@aux@backref

% don't expand the list all the way, just expand it once
\def\blx@addpageref#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@tempcnta\z@
  \let\blx@tempa\@empty
  \def\do##1{%
    \appto\blx@tempa{{##1}}%
    \advance\blx@tempcnta\@ne}%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@pref@\the\c@refsection @#1}%
  \edef\blx@tempa{\endgroup\noexpand\blx@bbl@listdef
    {pageref}{\the\blx@tempcnta}{\expandonce{\blx@tempa}}}%
  \blx@tempa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
\clearpage
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
\clearpage
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
\clearpage
foo
\clearpage
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.

\mainmatter
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
\clearpage
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
\clearpage
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.
\clearpage
foo
\clearpage
Trying to cite \cite{sigfridsson}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma y Ulf Ryde (1998). “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. En: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, págs. 377-395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P (vid. págs. i, ii, iii, v, 1-3, 5).]

As far as I can tell, things work fine. The only downside is that the Roman numerals produced in Spanish style are not compressed like Arabic and normal Roman numerals ("i-iii" for example).

Further testing would be greatly appreciated. Issuescan be reported at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/.